# Как вызвать глобальную переменную в соседнем файле?

Tags: python

Есть два файла, как переменную w вызвать во втором файле

первый week_of_the_days.py

```
import random
def days_of_the_week():
    """Выбираем случайный день недели."""
    global w                            #  Объявляем глобальную переменную.
    week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    w = random.choice(week) # Использую модуль random с методом choice - Выбор случайного элемента из списка.

    print("Сегодняшний день недели : ", w)

days_of_the_week()
```

второй файл zoopark_open.py

```
from week_of_the_days import days_of_the_week


def Zoopark():
    """Привествие пришедших в зоопарк."""

    days_of_the_week()   # Какой сегодня день.
    if w == 'Monday':
        print("Зоопарк закрыт, приходите в другой день.")
    else:
        print("----####---- Добро пожаловать в зоопарк!----####----")
        print("----####---- В нашем зоопарке 5 вальеров с животными. ----####----")


Zoopark()

# Вывод: NameError: name 'w' is not defined
```

Comment: w и в первом файле не определена. И зачем вообще она глобальная?

Comment: global w в первом не нужна проверил ок, global w для того чтобы загрузить из функции первого файла во второй файл день недели случайный.

Comment: Правильный подход: возвращать из функции значение, а не обращаться напрямую к внутренним переменным.

Comment: т.е return w в первом файле

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: прописал в первом файле заместо принта - return w ,  все равно NameError: name 'w' is not defined во втором .

Comment: Так теперь надо это значение присвоить какой-то переменной во втором файле и уже с ней работать.

Comment: w = days_of_the_week()   # Какой сегодня день.
print("Сегодняшний день недели : ", days_of_the_week()) так работает

Comment: Спасибо Эникейщик!

Comment: Нет не работает все равно, в Monday зоопарк не закрывает.

Comment: Если вы применили все рекомендованные исправления, то все работает. И в понедельник зоопарк закрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`week_of_the_days.py`

```
def days_of_the_week():
    from random import choice
    """Выбираем случайный день недели."""
    week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    return choice(week)  # Передаем результат работы функции
```

---

`zookark_open.py`

```
from week_of_the_days import days_of_the_week


def zoopark():
    """Привествие пришедших в зоопарк."""
    working_days = ('Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday',)
    day = days_of_the_week()  # Присваиваем переменной результат работы импортированной функции
    if day not in working_days:  # Если функция вернула результат не соответствующий рабочему дню
                            # выводим сообщение о том, что зоопарк закрыт
        print('Сегодня - {}\n'
              'Зоопарк закрыт, приходите в другой день.\n'
              'Зоопарк работает:\n{}\nс 10:00 до 20:00'.format(day, ', '.join(working_days)))
    else:  # Если результат работы функции соответствует рабочему дню... Выводим приветствие
        print("----####---- Добро пожаловать в зоопарк!----####----\n"
              "----####---- В нашем зоопарке 5 вальеров с животными. ----####----")


zoopark()
```

Comment: сек, только второй файл  zoopark_open.py - название файла второе

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, всмысле?

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, вывод во втором файле немного поменял

Comment: два раза тут написал week_of_the_days.py ну это мелочи. А в коде не выводит, что закрыт.

Comment: ----####---- Добро пожаловать в зоопарк!----####----
----####---- В нашем зоопарке 5 вальеров с животными. ----####----

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, оба файла поменяйте. Или нужно первый использовать как есть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85072/discussion-between-andrey-and--).

Comment: да все ок поменял, я понял он выводит один раз так : Сегодня - Monday
Зоопарк закрыт, приходите в другой день.
Зоопарк работает:
Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
с 10:00 до 20:00

Comment: Это как я понял по понедельникам

Comment: а в другие дни так ----####---- Добро пожаловать в зоопарк!----####----
----####---- В нашем зоопарке 5 вальеров с животными. ----####----

Comment: Я так понимаю субботу и воскресенье

Comment: Там из рабочих дней убраны понедельник и вторник, если нужен просто понедельник сделать не рабочим, добавьте в рабочие дни вторник

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, Если нужно что-бы работал только по выходным, уберите из кортежа с рабочими днями все кроме субботы и воскресенья

Comment: Хорошо спасибо!

Comment: @Andrey А зачем вы отклоняете правку, и те же изменения вносите сами?

Comment: @0xdb Случайно получилось